# Eclipse launch error 13 - Windows 10 with Java 1.8.0_31

Tags: java, eclipse, launch

After i upgraded Java on my **Windows 10, eclipse will not start**. It gives an **error upon launch**.

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MjXY.png)

There are multiple ways to resolve this; it depends upon the root cause and many solutions are discussed in other threads. Here's what i did to solve it in my machine.

My "Path" variable (System Environment Variables) had two paths as below.

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin
```

**Moving the JDK path above the Oracle Java Path solved the issue for me. The order in which they appear has to be changed as below.**

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath
```

[Path Listing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXkE4.png)

Comment: If you want to provide an answer to something you must still ask a question and then write an answer. But this question is asked several times a week and has many existing answers.

Comment: Yea, i can't answer that question since i don't have minimum points.  None of the answers in that thread helped me; had to find the solution that worked for me which is explained above and I assume there are others for whom this only work. Just a thought.

Comment: Yes, but if you create a new Question the text should just be a question. You should then create an Answer containing the answer. Putting the answer in the question body is against the rules.